# Upgrading from D2005 to D2010 : TRichEdit

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, trichedit

The following code works well on D2005 :

```
  MyRichEdit1.Text := TMemoField(Query1.FieldByName('Msg')).asString;
```

But in D2010, this code outputs the text in plain text and not on rtf.

To solve the problem I'm using the following code

```
MyRichEdit1.PlainText := False;
MyRichEdit1.Text := TMemoField(Query1.FieldByName('Msg')).asString;
MyRichEdit1.PlainText := TRUE;
MyRichEdit1.Lines.SaveToFile('Lixo.Rtf');
MyRichEdit1.PlainText := False;
MyRichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile('Lixo.Rtf');
```

How can I import rtf text from a database to a TRichEdit without having to use a file in the process?
I tried the solution on 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074383/loading-rtf-text-from-database-into-trichedit)
but it doesn't work, it appear in plain text and with a space between each char.

Thanks
Sam

Comment: it's hard to believe that code would ever have loaded rich text

Comment: I am migrating from BCB6 to C++ Builder XE and having the same problem. Its really frustrating trying to solve something that could be avoided. Just can't comprehend why the Delphi programmers need to change interface to already functioning thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to load RTF code into a `TRichEdit`, then place the RTF into a `TStream` object and use the RichEdit's `LoadFromStream()` method with the `PlainText` property set to False.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for C++ Builder XE, but analogous could be used for Delphi.

```
UnicodeString str = L"{\\rtf1 \\qr r{\\sub nom} = ----}"; // some rtf coded text
stream = new TStringStream();
stream->Clear();
stream->WriteString(str);
stream->Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
MyRichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(stream);
delete stream;
stream = NULL;
```